# Game Theory related to payoff matrix of 2x3 checkboard where domino is placed on it

Tags: game-theory

A domino piece can be placed on a 2 × 3 checkerboard in seven different ways:
The first player places the domino and the second player selects one of the six squares. If
the selected square is covered by the domino, then the second player wins; otherwise the
first player wins. Is this game fair? What are the optimal strategies? Can you exploit the
symmetries? How do your findings generalize to larger boards?

I have difficulty in writing the payoff matrix. I know that a good strategy to choose for player 2 is to place the domino somewhere in the center however, I cannot come up with the matrix.

Comment: Give a name to cells; e.g. "a,b,c,d,e,f". A strategy from Player 1 may be called "ab" for placing the piece on the cells "a,b" and a strategy from Player 2 may be called "a" is she picks "a". Then draw the $7 \times 6$ matrix for this zero-sum game.

Comment: Did you find an accurate solution ?